# @support condition in CSS to validate element id

Tags: css, thingworx

How to check element id while using @support in css
We are using Thingworx to develop UI for our app.
Below code changes all the button in UI

```
@supports (ptcs-style-unit: "PTCS-BUTTON.primary"){
  :host {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 2px;  
  }
}
```

Is it possible to check button id in @support ?
This is how my page HTML looks
[image: HTML]
Note : This is auto generated HTML from Thingworx Platform
I tried adding and condition in @support which doesn't work

```
@supports (ptcs-style-unit: "PTCS-BUTTON.primary") and (ptcs-button : "root_ptcsbutton-12") {
  :host {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 2px;  
  }
}
```

Comment: `@supports` checks for CSS keys and values, not whether a certain type of element exists or has a certain attribute (like `id`). For that you have the regular attribute and id selectors, like plain old CSS. What would `supports "pcts-style-unit" with value "PICS-BUTTON.primary"` even mean?